# Is it possible to get the SessionContext from JBoss without going through an EJB?

Tags: jboss, ejb, sessioncontext

All the answers I read discuss the container injecting the SessionContext on the EJB itself, but what if I wanted to get at the current SessionContext without having an EJB?

Answer (score 0):

If you know any EJB name for which you would like to get Context somewhere inside a servlet then you could do something like below. But trying to get context without EJB context will result in NameNotFoundException.

> InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
>   SessionContext sctxLookup = (SessionContext) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/com.TestBean/sctx");